# Raspberry Pi - ALSA error when trying to record sound through an audio card and playback

Tags: alsa, raspberry-pi-zero

## Hello,

I am working on trying to play audio out of a raspberry pi zero W(ssh connection), and I bought an audio card, which led me to this Wiki tutorial to set it up.

[Wiki Page]
https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_2_Mics_Pi_HAT/

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/respeaker/mic_hat)

After I install all the repos and sudo upgrade, I try to test it out by completing step 3:
[image]

However, when I enter the command into the terminal, I get this error:
[image]

```
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1822:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card  
arecord: main:828: audio open error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1822:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
aplay: main:828: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Please can someone help - I will be online to provide any extra information.

## Thank you

Comment: Did you find out what this was ?